# Facebook payments, credit api , Test users can't get the details of test transaction order_id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-credits

I am using Facebook Credits.

I have set my user id as test user in app dashboard payments section.

Evey thing works fine, the transaction completed successfully, I get the order_id , then while fetching the details of that order_id to check whether it exists or not, the facebook Api gives the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request. thrown in
```

and testing by file_get_contents gives the following error

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

Using cUrl for checking its details also didn't work.

and the big point is that when i copy the link ( which is to be executed either by Facebook graph api, file_get_contents, and by cUrl ) and paste it in url, It works very fine.

I am so much worried, what is the problem with Facebook api, file_get_contents.

Kindly help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, test orders are not retrievable via the API.

This is mentioned on the [Order API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/order/) -

> Note: You must use real orders when calling the Graph API.
>   Transactions from the users listed in the 'Payments Testers' section
>   of your app settings are not be processed and will not appear in the
>   Order API

Comment: I was just curious , why it works when i put the link in simple browser url and it shows me the correct results

Comment: let suppose i get the test order id "123456789" and i put the link https://graph.facebook.com/123456789?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx in the browser, It gives me result, but didn't gets through file_get_contents or Facebook graph api

Comment: There should be no difference between the two calls (the manual browser call and the call from your PHP code)...

Comment: That's why i am so worried, I am worried may it not create problems in real payments :(